# Common Table Expression Issue

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, common-table-expression

To calculate [clustering coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clustering_coefficient) I have created the following query:

```
--calculate embeddedness and local_gatekepping_role_count (for two-way connections)
    declare @observedUser varchar(50)
    declare @clusteringCoefficient decimal(18, 7)
    declare @possibleConnectionsCount int
    declare @neighborConnectionsCount int
    declare @rowsAffected int
    SET @rowsAffected = 1;
    WHILE @rowsAffected > 0
    BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 1 @observedUser = msisdn FROM users_in_group_91 WHERE clustering_coefficient IS NULL
    SET @rowsAffected = @@ROWCOUNT
    IF @rowsAffected = 0 break;
    ;WITH neighbors AS
    (
    SELECT called_party AS neighbor FROM connections_in_group_91 WHERE calling_party = @observedUser
    UNION
    SELECT calling_party AS neighbor FROM connections_in_group_91 WHERE called_party = @observedUser
    ),
    possibleConnections AS
    (
    SELECT n1.neighbor AS user1, n2.neighbor AS user2 FROM neighbors n1 CROSS JOIN neighbors n2 WHERE n1.neighbor < n2.neighbor
    )
    SELECT @clusteringCoefficient = CAST(COUNT(*) AS decimal)/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM possibleConnections) FROM possibleConnections pc INNER JOIN connections_in_group_91 c91 ON c91.calling_party = pc.user1 AND c91.called_party = pc.user2
    )
    UPDATE users_in_group_91 SET clustering_coefficient = @clusteringCoefficient WHERE msisdn = @observedUser
    END
```

which works fine.As there would be useful to check how many times the observed user plays the role of gatekeeper I tried to modify the query above the following way:

```
declare @observedUser varchar(50)
    declare @clusteringCoefficient decimal(18, 7)
    declare @gatekeepingRoleCount int
    declare @possibleConnectionsCount int
    declare @neighborConnectionsCount int
    declare @rowsAffected int
    SET @rowsAffected = 1;
    WHILE @rowsAffected > 0
    BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 1 @observedUser = msisdn FROM users_in_group_91 WHERE clustering_coefficient IS NULL
    SET @rowsAffected = @@ROWCOUNT
    IF @rowsAffected = 0 break;
    ;WITH neighbors AS
    (
    SELECT called_party AS neighbor FROM connections_in_group_91 WHERE calling_party = @observedUser
    UNION
    SELECT calling_party AS neighbor FROM connections_in_group_91 WHERE called_party = @observedUser
    ),
    possibleConnections AS
    (
    SELECT n1.neighbor AS user1, n2.neighbor AS user2 FROM neighbors n1 CROSS JOIN neighbors n2 WHERE n1.neighbor < n2.neighbor
    )
    SELECT @possibleConnectionsCount = COUNT(*) FROM possibleConnections
    SELECT @clusteringCoefficient = CAST(COUNT(*) AS decimal)/(@possibleConnectionsCount) FROM possibleConnections pc INNER JOIN connections_in_group_91 c91 ON c91.calling_party = pc.user1 AND c91.called_party = pc.user2
    SET @gatekeepingRoleCount = @possibleConnectionsCount * (1 - @clusteringCoefficient)
    UPDATE users_in_group_91 SET clustering_coefficient = @clusteringCoefficient, local_gatekeeping_role_count = @gatekeepingRoleCount WHERE msisdn = @observedUser
    END
```

but the latter query returns an error: **Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 25
Invalid object name 'possibleConnections'.**

Does anyone know why it is not possible to query the same expression multiple times this way and how to modify the query above in order to calculate @clusteringCoefficient and @gatekeepingRoleCount in the same loop?

Thank you!

Comment: @KM from past performance, it looks like the OP uses SO as a convenient helpdesk and very little else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CTE is only good for the following statement.

In your case if you get rid of the scalar variables and just put the subqueries inline it should work.

Comment: you're new here, but you'll figure it out... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parasite

Comment: Borrowing wisdom at wikipedia is worse than gaining knowledge at SO:)